# How can I disable HideTabBar and ShowAllTabs in macOS in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I just created a Hello world project in macOS-SwiftUI, then if I click on **Show Tab Bar** or **Show All Tabs** from **View**, it is going show tabs and bring all open tabs, I do not want my project give possibility for such a action to user, how can I disable those functions from bace?

[image]

[image]